# Selecting a piece of the picture with the cursor and zoom the same

Tags: android, cursor, imageview

I have ImageView and I want to mark a part from that for zooming.
I need something like "Select" in Paint.

How I can do it with the Cursor or otherwise?

I just need help with selecting.

Something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, but at the beginning will be the point. Square is drawn at the end

```
imageViewDisplaySectrum.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        float rectX,rectY,rectX2,rectY2;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   

                    rectX = event.getX();
                    rectY = event.getY();

                    rectX2 = rectX;
                    rectY2 = rectY;

                    canvasDisplaySpectrum.drawPoint(rectX , rectY , paintRect);
                    imageViewDisplaySectrum.invalidate();                       

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    rectX2 = event.getX();
                    rectY2 = event.getY();              

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    canvasDisplaySpectrum.drawRect(rectX, rectY, rectX2, rectY2, paintRect);
                    imageViewDisplaySectrum.invalidate();

                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

---

```
        paintRect = new Paint();

        paintRect.setColor(Color.RED);
        paintRect.setStrokeWidth(3);
        paintRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```